# Como renderizar columnas Dinámicas a partir de otro array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-objeto

Tengo dos variables con los datos que me devuelve mi base de datos en formato `array`, al cual la variable datos, contiene todos los datos que deseo renderizar en mi tabla, y la variable `concept` tiene la clave de las columnas dinámicas, en este caso vendría a ser la columna FAENAS,MULTAS. Lo que deseo es renderizar dinámicamente los valores que me devuelva mi base de datos.

```js
data: function(){
      datos:[{n_docu:"23248169",l_agen:"USUARIO",FAENAS:"1.00",MULTAS:"0.00"},
             {n_docu:"71377558",l_agen:"SIMEON",FAENAS:"5.00",MULTAS:"1.00"}, 
             {n_docu:"46117631",l_agen:"EGUAVIL",FAENAS:"0.00",MULTAS:"1.00"}],
      concept:[{c_prod:"000004",l_prod:"FAENAS"},
               {c_prod:"000005",l_prod:"MULTAS"}]
},


<table class="table table-hover table-sm table-bordered table-light mb-0">
   <thead>
         <tr>
           <th scope="col">Codigo</th>
           <th scope="col">Apellido y Nombre/razòn social</th>
           <th scope="col" v-for="c in concept" v-text="c.l_prod"></th>
         </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
         <tr v-for="d in datos">
            <td v-text="d.n_docu"></td>
            <td v-text="d.l_agen"></td>
            <td v-for="c in concept" v-text="d+'.'+c.l_prod"></td>
         </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

He tratado de varias formas y no consigo lograrlo.

```
<tr v-for="d in datos">
    <td v-text="d.n_docu"></td>
    <td v-text="d.l_agen"></td>
    <td v-for="c in concept" v-text="d+'.'+c.l_prod"></td>
</tr>
```

y lo que obtengo es lo siguiente:

| Codigo | Apellido y Nombre/razòn social | FAENAS | MULTAS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23248169 | USUARIO | [object object].FAENAS | [object object].MULTAS |
| 71377558 | SIMEON | [object object].FAENAS | [object object].MULTAS |
| 46117631 | EGUAVIL | [object object].FAENAS | [object object].MULTAS |

LO QUE DESEO OBTENER:

| Codigo | Apellido y Nombre/razòn social | FAENAS | MULTAS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23248169 | USUARIO | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| 71377558 | SIMEON | 5.00 | 1.00 |
| 46117631 | EGUAVIL | 0.00 | 1.00 |

Espero me halla dejado entender, gracias de antemano...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es acceder a la propiedad del objeto `d`,  cuyo nombre es igual al valor contenido en la variable `c.l_prod`.
La sintaxis correcta para esto es:

```
// Ejemplo
let value = d[c.l_prod];
```

#### Solución:

```
<tr v-for="d in datos">
    <td v-text="d.n_docu"></td>
    <td v-text="d.l_agen"></td>
    <td v-for="c in concept" v-text="d[c.l_prod]"></td>
</tr>
```

---

Referencias:

- [Notación por corchetes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#notaci.c3.b3n_por_corchetes)